# Use shiny text input and dplyr to filter rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to use the text input widget on a shiny app to filter rows in a data frame but I can’t get it working.

**Dataset**

```
df1<-data.frame (Name=c("Carlos","Pete","Carlos","Carlos","Carlos","Pete","Pete","Pete","Pete","Homer"),Sales=(as.integer(c("3","4","7","6","4","9","1","2","1","9"))))
```

**UI**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Sales trends"),titlePanel("People score"),

sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(

  textInput("text", label = h3("Text input"), value = "Enter text..."),

  numericInput("obs", "Number of observations to view:", 3),

  helpText("Note: while the data view will show only the specified",
           "number of observations, the summary will still be based",
           "on the full dataset."),

  submitButton("Update View")
),

mainPanel(
  h4("Volume: Total sales"),
  verbatimTextOutput("volume"),

  h4("Top people"),
  tableOutput("view")
))))
```

**Server**

```
library(shiny)
library (dplyr)
df1<-data.frame (Name=c("Carlos","Pete","Carlos","Carlos","Carlos","Pete","Pete","Pete","Pete","Homer"),Sales=(as.integer(c("3","4","7","6","4","9","1","2","1","9"))))
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$value <- renderPrint({ input$text })
datasetInput <- reactive({
switch(input$dataset,df1%>% filter(Name %in% "input$text")%>% select(Name, Sales)%>% arrange(desc(Sales)))
})
output$volume <- renderPrint({
dataset <- datasetInput()
sum(dataset$Sales)
})})
```

Comment: Maybe try removing the quotes from around `input$text` inside `filter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As aosmith pointed out, you need to remove the quotes for filtering. Second, you should use `==` instead of `%in%` inside of `filter()`. Third, you would use `switch()` in other cases (read up on `?switch`), but here you don't need it.

Your `server.R` should look like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data_frame(Name = c("Carlos","Pete","Carlos","Carlos","Carlos","Pete",
                         "Pete","Pete","Pete","Homer"),
                  Sales = c(3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 9, 1, 2, 1, 9))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    df1 %>% filter(Name == input$text) %>% arrange(desc(Sales))
  })
  output$volume <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- datasetInput()
    dataset$Sales
  })
})
```

Comment: trying to run the OP's ui.R along with this server.R you provided just gives me `Error: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "function"` errors.

Comment: You need to define the data in `server.R`. I had skipped that part, but I updated my answers to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Now I get `Warning: Error in switch: EXPR must be a length 1 vector` when the app launches.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck did you restart your r session and load only those two packages? could you try to track down, where and when the error is occurring? How are you launching the app?

Answer (score 1):

when you filter with your own search words,
1. make update function with: `reactive`
2. input the function within `renderDT`

```
ui = fluidPage(
        textInput('qry', 'Species', value='setosa'),
        DT::DTOutput('tbl'))
server = function(input, output){
        a = reactive({ filter(iris, Species == input$qry })
        output$tbl = renderDT(a())
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

good luck!